# Store dataset results in IList

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

How would I store results from dataset in an Ilist?

```
Model read = new Model()
IList<sqlprop> sqlprop= read.readrows("SELECT * FROM test").Tables[0].Cast<DataRow>().ToList();

Class Model
{
public DataSet readrows(string query)
        {
            ............
            return dataset;
        }
}

Class sqlprop
{
string data1 get;set;
string data2 get;set;
.........
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "how to convert `DataRow` to `sqlprop`"?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, and your code sample has a lot of problems obscuring the intent of the sample.

Comment: Yes convert the datarow to sqlprop.

Comment: Can I ask, did I answer your question (ultimately) below?  If so you could mark it as the accepted answer if not, let me know how I can help further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would do what you want I think...

```
List<sqlprop> sqlprop= read
    .readrows("SELECT * FROM test")
    .Tables[0]
    .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => new sqlprop
                     {
                         data1 = r.GetString(0),
                         data2 = r.GetString(1)
                     })
    .ToList();
```

You should check for DBNull.Value and probably include the column name in the SQL query etc, etc, but you get the idea.

**Update**

If you need it to be generic and the column name in the database exactly matches the property name you could do something like this (untested, I have no compiler here but it should give you the idea):

```
List<sqlprop> sqlprop= read
    .readrows("SELECT * FROM test")
    .Tables[0]
    .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => {
        var ret = new sqlprop();
        foreach (var p in ret.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object val = r[r.Table.Columns.IndexOf(p.Name)];
            if (val != DBNull.Value)
            {
                p.SetValue(ret, val, null);
            }
        }
        return ret;
     })
    .ToList();
```

NOTE:  This is a bit flaky and not super efficient but anyway, there it is!

Comment: Great but is there anyway to make this more dynamic? I have hundres of sql queries so I do not want to manually write ....GetString(xxx) etc. Is there a way to have it fill in the matching columns/variables automatically?

Comment: @user719825 that sounds like you don't want to be using datasets then

Comment: Yeah, I agree that there is probably a better approach than doing this with datasets, but there you go anyway, enjoy!

Comment: One problem. I am getting a " Does not contain a definition for Cast aand the best extension method overload" for .Cast<DataRow>()

Comment: oh, sorry, you probably need to use the Rows property - updated the code

Comment: amazing! one last error on var ret= new sqlprop() <--The type or namespace name 'sqlprop' could not be found.
...And again thanks for the help in such a short time. We need a paypal donate button for you.

Comment: Ok i think the problem is actually rdr.Getvalue and rdr.Get Ordinal. I do not have a reader setup. Do I need one in my dataset to use this code?

Comment: ah, sorry, yes, of course you have a DataRow at that point, which I think has a Table property, which would have a columns collection where you could get the index of a given column by name - updated the code to show you

Comment: Ok we are soo close!! The issue is object val = r.Item <-- 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method.

Comment: ah, ha, yup, you do not need the Item property - that should work fine now (I actually have a compiler and tested it out)